# What is the equavelent of mysql : SET in laravel 4.2?

Tags: laravel

i am new to Laravel and now trying to use transaction in Laravel 4.2
I am trying to replace this Mysql query in laravel.

```
UPDATE managerStock SET amount = amount + $productAmount WHERE manager_id = '$receiverID' and product_id='$productID
```

So far i came up with this code

```
DB::table('distributorStock')->where('distributor_id','=','senderID')->where('manager_id','=','receiverID')->update(array('amount' => ''));
```

I am looking for your kind help regarding this challenge!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you want to replace bellow mysql query -

```
UPDATE managerStock SET amount = amount + $productAmount WHERE manager_id = '$receiverID' and product_id='$productID'
```

Possible answer could be -

```
$dbData = DB::table('managerStock')->where('manager_id', $receiverID)->where('product_id', $productID)->first();
$dbData->amount = $dbData->amount+$productAmount;
$dbData->save();
```

for more than one database query as a transaction you can use -

```
DB::transaction(function() use ($dbData1, $dbData2, $dbData3) {
  $dbData1->save();
  $dbData2->save();
  $dbData3->save();
});
```